# trying to start an image in docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to do this lab and type in the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it --name bdu_spark2 -P -p 4040:4040 -p 4041:4041 -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 bigdatauniversity/spark2:latest /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
```

But I get the following error. Is there a conflict between port 8080 of docker using it and other software trying to use it? I have restarted docker and made sure no other containers are running. Thanks for all the input.

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 3c62472fe5f8481e5ee957550078f06106b45fc6bffe25669272e2ea924b5f36: failed to create endpoint bdu_spark2 on network bridge: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
```

Comment: seems your port 8080 is already in use. check with sudo netstat -tulpn  which application is using it and close it or change the port from your local machine that is mapped to the container e.g. -p 8880:8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually caused because another container is using 8080 port on your docker host.

You can see your running containers by running: $ sudo docker ps

Either stop the other container, or choose a different host port to map your container's 8080 to.

Comment: Changing the port to 8082:8082 seems to have worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

In my case doing this with MySQL, I didn't realize it was because I already had a native MySQL running on that port.

```
docker run --name db --detach --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123" --publish=3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

I did a `netstat  --all  --numeric --program  --inet  --timers  | grep 3306` and noticed it gave me `1418/mysqld`. Then I did a `ps aux | grep mysql` and noticed that was the same process number started by `/usr/sbin/mysqld` which was my local MySQL instance on my host, nothing to do with containers.

Double check nothing is using those ports, especially 8080, which is very common for stand alone web servers, like those that ship with IDEs.

If you are using that port, you can use the --publish option to specify the host port to be different but still use the same port on the container. i.e. `--publish=8081:8080`, hostport:containerport.